# Change database image location for transportability

Tags: wp-query, images, options

**The problem:** the worpress site is developed locally by my team. When we finish, we will put it online. Now, changing the `siteurl`, `home` and `ossdl_off_cdn_url` in the database `table wp_options`is easy to change. But we have to change all URL in post data, especially the links that lead to the images.

We want, when we post a new image, that is registered in the database by:

```
<img src="/wp-content/etc/....
```

And not:

```
<img src="http://siteurl/wp-content/etc/....
```

There is a plugin or a mod to do so?

We have already ran this query:

```
UPDATE wp_posts SET `post_content` = REPLACE (`post_content`, 'src="http://siteurl', 'src="');
```

To cancel all reference URL and get image directly from the site root folder `/wp-content` but we do not want to do this also for future images.

Comment: So you want to force relative URLs?

Comment: I don't know if it calls "relative", probably yes. Wanto to force contents link to local /wp-content

Comment: But WordPress already uses relative paths for images... Except for the `GUID` column. I never had trouble developing on local and moving it online. Only had to change `siteurl` and `home`.